# Regarding interfaces of classes in OOP

Tags: object-oriented, interfaces

When one says "a class' interface":

Does he/she refer to all of the get and set methods - or do they refer only to the methods' signatures and return types, without the inner implementation of these methods? (Aka, the implementation of a 'get' method isn't considered part of the interface, but rather part of the inner implementation of the class. The interface is the return type for that method and the signature of that method).

Comment: Don't over think it my friend. An interface is defined by how you interact with something. You can replace *something* with *class* and it still applies.

Answer (score 3):

If you're doing interfaces properly, the interface consists of the *signature* of the methods and the *model semantics* of the methods. That second part is important — you almost certainly wouldn't want a `SumTheColumnContents` method to actually launch a preemptive thermonuclear strike on the neighbors prized goldfish — yet it's not really all that possible for the compiler to enforce. (Determining when two general pieces of code do the same thing is A Stupendously Hard Problem, as it includes the famous Halting Problem, and indeed most interesting challenges in mathematical proofs, as *sub-problems*.) So you have to be well-behaved and not go round doing nasty things. Of course, this is just the good old Liskov Substitution Principle with a fully abstract class as the superclass; if the semantics of the subclasses are wildly different, they won't be interchangeable with each other even even if the signature is the same.

This is all independent of how some random programming language describes or implements an interface. It's a much more general concept than that. (Yes, some call them “interfaces”, and others call them “protocols”, and some just call them “abstract superclasses”. The idea is still the same.)

Comment: For the sake of completeness, by *A Stupendously Hard Problem* Donal actually means [undecidable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undecidable_problem). It's possible to prove/disprove that two specific programs do the same thing, but it's *impossible* to give an algorithm that'll give a correct answer it for *any* pair of programs.

Answer (score 2):

The interface doesn't include implementation details, by definition.  It's the way you interact with the 'thing', so another 'thing' could be created which does the same thing, even if its innards are completely different.

The problem with get and set methods is that they tell you what they're doing to the innards of the thing.  A method named `.getZebra()` tells me that there's a variable named `zebra` in that thing; otherwise it would have been named `.zebra()`, and you wouldn't know whether it's stored or calculated or what.

If someone wants to come along and reimplement your thing differently (possibly you, later on), and your interface is sprinkled with getters and setters, then there's a choice of a) breaking the interface, b) using the same variables to represent it, constraining the design unnecessarily, or c) simulating the presence of those variables in the new code, complicating the design unnecessarily.   It's possible that you might get lucky and that your interface is nice and you won't need to do those things, but if you use names like `getX()` and `setY()`, you're thinking in terms of the variables x and y that you have, not what they represent abstractly.

Setters also force your object to be mutable, and the meaning of what you're trying to do may not require that.

The implementation of getters and setters is not guaranteed by the words 'get' or 'set', so technically you can say that they're part of the class interface and that therefore there's no encapsulation violation, but really there is.  Programmers use words to mean something, and when they put 'get' or 'set' at the beginning of a method name, they're saying "this is implemented as a variable".

The inside and outside of a class (or object) are at different levels of abstraction; the inside is all about how it's done, the outside is all about what can be done.  The naming should reflect the distinction.

If you find yourself writing an object that has lots of getters and setters, and you can't find a reasonable way to rename them, what you have is probably a data structure, not an object.

Comment: Hum, in C#, GetFoo() usually mean that the returned value is computed and is potentially expensive. Properties (the get/set equivalent of java) can be computed if its cheap. So "get mean accessing a field"  may not be a universal rule of programming. Scala also allow those "it's computed but you wouldn't know it" properties. And in Java, I've been using getBar() to get a computed properties for years now. Do you have a source for that convention that computed is foo() and field is getFoo()? I am not saying it's wrong, but I can't remember seeing that convention in the codebase I worked on.

Comment: I'm not familiar with C# and couldn't find anything about get implying that it isn't stored.  I'm not saying "there is a convention that foo() is computed and getFoo() is a field", I'm saying "there is a convention that getFoo() and setFoo() mean that there is a field foo that can be retreived or mutated, and this is horribly broken because it means that the interface must act like a variable".  When you use getBar() in Java for computed properties, wouldn't it make more sense to just say bar()?

Comment: For C#, [you may want to read this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229054(v=vs.100).aspx). Its not really about Get per say, but more about properties = cheap and method = may not be cheap. As for Java, well, yes, I totally agree that bar() is more compact, but a lot of framework and developper have gone by the convention of "get set" and it's better to follow an imperfect convention that being inconsistent. I think there is a difference between a "logical" property of a class and a field : one is part of the interface, the other an implementation detail

Comment: I sure created a lot of interface that had a few `get` on them. `Entity` with a `getId`, with the contract of : I don't care how you find your id, but it must be cheap, consistent, and be unique to you. Or a generic `Report` with `getTitle`. Different implementation created the title using different strings. Some implementation did it on the fly, other just delegated to a collaborator. If someone assumed that there was a field behing `getTitle`, they would have been pretty sad indeed...

Comment: @LaurentBourgault-Roy:  Just because a convention exists doesn't mean it's a good idea.  This convention suggests that a C-style struct with a bunch of boilerplate is a perfectly good object, and that the difference between the interface and implementation of an object is unimportant.

Answer (score 1):

The interface to a class is essentially what is visible to other classes using it.

The interface to a class would therefore be the declarations of all the public methods and variables it exposes.  It wouldn't include the implementation details of each method.

Where a class has protected (or package private for Java) methods and variables, then they should also be considered part of the interface, since they can also be accessed by other classes, albeit with some restrictions.